# Detecting origin of an ngModelChange event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

While trying to filter the options visible inside a `mat-selection-list` by modifying the array on which the `ngFor` iterated on to generate the available `mat-list-option` I am losing the existing state of which options were checked since an `ngModelChange` event is fired even though, the user didn't really click on anything

```
<mat-selection-list
     name="userSelection"
     [ngModel]="selectedUsers"
     (ngModelChange)="onSelectedUsersChange($event)">
         <mat-list-option *ngFor="let user of users"
                 [value]="user"
                 checkboxPosition="before"
                 [title]="user.name">
                     {{ user.name }}
         </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

And the typescript code:

```
applyUserSearchFilter(username: string) {
    if (!isNullOrWhitespace(username)) {
        this.users = this.usersOriginal.filter(
            u => u.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(username.toLowerCase()) > -1
        );
    } else {
        this.users = this.usersOriginal;
    }
}

onSelectedUsersChange(e: any) {
    this.selectedUsers = e;
}
```

When running this method, if I have two options `A` and `B`, both checked and then run this while filtering for `C`, both options disappear, which is what I want.

But then when I clear the filter, both options are visible again but not checked.

The reason for this I suspect is when both options disappear because of the filter, `onSelectedUsersChange` is triggered, with an empty array.

Is there any way I can selectively not trigger that event, or know whether `onSelectedUsersChange` was triggered due to user interaction or script cascading events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to use `selectionChange` instead of `ngModelChange` while still binding with `ngModel`.

`selectionChange` passes an object with which you can either push into or splice `selectedUsers` based on whether the option is selected on not.

Lastly, at the end of `applyUserSearchFilter` I made sure the user selection is reapplied by adding `this.selectedUsers = clone(this.selectedUsers);`. `clone` is a method we have to clone objects.